# Ajax 3.5 in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I had convert my web application from visual studio 2003(framework 1.1) to visual studio 2010(framework 4.0).
After converted, I have pug-in Ajax 3.5 and test my web application.
The web application run well but the Ajax doesn't work.
There are not error appear in the application also.

What can I do in other to make the Ajax work???

Please advice...Thanks in advance.

Comment: Define "doesn't work."  Show the code that isn't doing what you expect and explain how the observed behavior differs from the expected behavior.  Do some debugging and tell us where the behaviors deviate, as well as what the runtime values are when the problem occurs.  Include any error messages generated by the system.  Seriously, we can't just _guess_ what your code looks like.

Comment: I expected when I click on the button, the autopostback feature won't bring me back to top of the page but it bring me back to the top of page after I click on the button. There are not error message occur just the Ajax did not take effective to remain the page position after autopostback.

Comment: <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <div>
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="a"><ContentTemplate >
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    </ContentTemplate></asp:UpdatePanel>
    
    </div>
    </form>
</body>

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

1. just remove the script managers from the pages and add it again how it was, from the Visual Studio tool box.
2. close the browser and run it.

It should work fine.

Comment: I had try many times.. but it still did not work.
Any ideas??